# How to use spread properties in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-next

Below is my code snippet and I would like to use additional argument (.i.e search) for connectionArgs.

```
const connectionArgs = require('graphql-relay').connectionArgs; 
users: {
      type: UserConnection.connectionType,
      args: {
        ...connectionArgs,
        search: {
          type: GraphQLString,
        },
      },
      resolve: async (obj, args, { user }) => {
        return UserLoader.loadUsers(user, args);
      }
    },
```

Above code works fine when using bable, but I am trying to remove babel (since async await is now supported in node 7.6v).
I get Unexpected token for connectionArgs.
Could any one suggest how to use this spread properties here ?

Comment: Node doesn’t support object spread yet.

Comment: @Ryan thank you for the reply, any other alternatives for node (to use this operator) ?

Comment: You might consider babel-node if you're currently compiling it for each run.

Comment: Object spread is not part of any ES standard.

Comment: [`...` is not an operator!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37152508/218196)